# Running batch to merge 2 files, adds an additional row to the end

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to add the contents of 100.txt to the beginning of all files carrying the wild card. It runs well but after it's done the output has an extra row with this  character at the end. How to remove it.

```
for %%a in (*sample_size_100*.gct) do copy 100.txt +"%%a" temp.tmp & move /Y temp.tmp "%%a"
```

(edited by Stephan: the character in question would not display here. It is a `Ctrl-Z`)

Comment: The character is like a standing rectangle.

Comment: The character is a `Ctrl-Z` Also known as EOF (EndOfFile). Try, if  `copy /b` helps.

Comment: Yes it did the trick. Thanks Stephan. If you write the answer down, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character is a Ctrl-Z Also known as EOF (EndOfFile). This occurs because `copy` without parameters copies in text mode. Add the `/b` switch for **b**inary:

```
copy /b 100.txt +"%%a" temp.tmp
```